# How many threads Parallel.For(Foreach) will create? Default MaxDegreeOfParallelism?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.5, parallel.foreach

I want to know, how many threads will be used when I run Parallel.For/ForEach loop.

I found, that it can be changed by MaxDegreeOfParallelism option.

MaxDegreeOfParallelism help on MSDN says ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx)):

> By default, For and ForEach will utilize however many threads the
>   underlying scheduler provides, so changing MaxDegreeOfParallelism from
>   the default only limits how many concurrent tasks will be used.

But I don't know how many threads underlying scheduler provides.

**How can I find out that?**

I could test it with loop with 9999999 runs, however this test will show me number, but not the rule that determine that number.

Edit/added later:

I googled for "sheduler max concurrency", and I found (at MSDN - [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.maximumconcurrencylevel.aspx)), that `TashSheduler` class has `MaximumConcurrencyLevel` property, and:

> Returns an integer that represents the maximum concurrency level. The
>   default scheduler returns Int32.MaxValue.

**That TaskSheduler class is used as "underlying scheduler" for these parallel loops?**

Comment: Interestingly, it returns the constant `2147483647`.. not `int32.MaxValue`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997402.aspx):

> The default scheduler for Task Parallel Library and PLINQ uses the .NET Framework `ThreadPool` to queue and execute work. In the .NET Framework 4, the `ThreadPool` uses the information that is provided by the `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` type to efficiently support the fine-grained parallelism (short-lived units of work) that parallel tasks and queries often represent.

Looking at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) of `ThreadPool`, it says:

> There is one thread pool per process. Beginning with the .NET Framework 4, the default size of the thread pool for a process depends on several factors, such as the size of the virtual address space. A process can call the `GetMaxThreads` method to determine the number of threads. The number of threads in the thread pool can be changed by using the `SetMaxThreads` method.